# Why setting a FormatConvertedBitmap as an alternate image source throws 'Source' not set exception?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

i'm trying to gray-out an item's image when the item it's unavailable. The following code should do the trick (handling all the possible image status: available, unavailable, non-existant). But the compiler keeps stating that image source it's not set, while it obiously is. Am i missing something? Thanks for any help.

Here is the image code:

```
<Image x:Name="cntFlag" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="20" Height="20" Margin="10,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" ToolTip="{Binding MatchData.Country_Id}">

<Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
        <Setter Property="Source">
            <Setter.Value>
            
                <Binding Path="MatchData.Country_Id" Converter="{StaticResource stringToBitmapImageConverter}" ConverterParameter="pack://application:,,,/media/images/flags/{0}.png">
                    <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                        <ImageSource>media/images/default/NoFlag.png</ImageSource>
                    </Binding.TargetNullValue>
                </Binding>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MatchData.IsMatchCancelledOrPostponed}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <FormatConvertedBitmap Source="{Binding Source, ElementName=cntFlag}" DestinationFormat="Gray8"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Image.Style>
```

Note: Commenting on the Style.Trigger section makes the code work, so the problem lies there...

UPDATE: In response to clemens' post: I modified the part of the code concerning the FormatConvertedBitmap method by inserting a direct link to the original image, leaving as the only discriminant for the execution of the trigger the occurrence of the condition IsMatchCancelledOrPostponed which should solve the problem he exposed . Unfortunately the result remains unchanged, with the exception that the error is detected directly by the XAML Designer this time.

Modifyied code:

```
<Setter.Value>
<FormatConvertedBitmap DestinationFormat="Gray8">
    <FormatConvertedBitmap.Source>
        <Binding Path="MatchData.Country_Id" Converter="{StaticResource stringToBitmapImageConverter}" ConverterParameter="pack://application:,,,/media/images/flags/{0}.png">
            <Binding.TargetNullValue>
                <ImageSource>media/images/default/NoFlag.png</ImageSource>
            </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
    </FormatConvertedBitmap.Source>
</FormatConvertedBitmap></Setter.Value>
```

Comment: Setting the Image's Source property to a FormatConvertedBitmap that has the same Source as its Source seems like a cyclic assignment.

Comment: If i am correct it's the same example posted in reply to your answer to similar question here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48848510/transform-a-colored-image-to-a-grayscale-image-using-xaml).

Comment: No, that's two Image elements.